# Image url given in CSS class is not working

Tags: css, dom, css-selectors

I've a css class with an image url, the path is correct as in inspect mode in Chrome I can see that class has loaded the image, but in the `<img />` element the image is not showing up. It works only when I put the Image path in its `src` property.

[image: 1]

In the screenshot, the red marked area is where I tried to use the class but not working, and the green marked area is where I put the image path in `src` property directly and its working.

I tried both `background` and `background-image` properties in CSS and none worked. For now I can settle it by using the `src` attribute instead of the css class, but my question is why the image is failing to render when passed using a css class?

Comment: Try to use absolute paths for asset linking i.e don't use '../'

Comment: @dantheman. I understood, but I don't know what the absolute path will be in the server after deployment, hence I have to use relative path

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correct, you use `background-image` on `img` tag. it's not best practice and it's not the purpose of this style rule. you can use `div` instead of `img` for `background-image`.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I was trying to use that 'background-image' directly as an inline style to see if its working, as using the class was not. I was just testing it out, if you look again, you can see that the style was commented out. I was just using the dev tools in Chrome to see if using css I can get that image to render.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it is working properly. We can see the calculator image in the background. Your problem is that your `<img>` has no `src` attribute (hence the icon with the broken image).

Comment: Thanks, Actually I wanted to use css class to render the image, hence I should not need to have an `src` attribute

Comment: If you don't plan to use `src` attribute why do you use `<img>` in the first place. `background-image` will work on any element.